# How do I set browser session attributes appropriately to protect what user ID is being sent in a HTTP request?

Tags: node.js, security, express, session, permissions

I am building a site with various users who have different levels of permissions and I want to make sure I'm using a secure pattern. The front end is Angular and the back-end is NodeJS, Express and MongoDB. There is also a TLS 1.1 connection encryption. For procedures that require a certain permission level, once I receive the HTTP request in Express, I use a middleware function to use the `req.session.user._id` to query that user from the DB and confirm that they have the appropriate level of permissions. If they do, I call next(), if not, I throw a session error.

The checking of permissions is all on the backend and so I assume that is secure, but if someone knows the ID of a user with a certain level of permission, is it possible for them to hack the browser session so that it send the user Id of the user with the higher permissions and gain access to the restricted procedure?

*More specifically, as Vasan noted in the comments below, what do I need to do to set the session attributes appropriately to ensure that the ID cookie is secured?*

**Edit:** So @Vasan's questions below reminded me that we actually are using express-session to create backend sessions and that I was confusing the browser session with that Express session. (Thanks Vasan!) I have modified the question to reflect both the original inquiry and subsequent re-focusing.

Comment: Depends on how you authenticate. Do you use passport with server-side sessions?

Comment: Oh yeah, I guess you are right. We are using express-session authenticated with a hashed password using pbkdf2-password. I was confusing that authenticated express session with the front-end browser session. I assume passport is just another way of doing the same thing?

Comment: Yes, more or less it is. If you use express-session, it uses server side session to store data, but it still uses a session ID cookie to load the session and a malicious user could spoof a logged-in user's session ID using that cookie. So ensure that the session ID cookie is secured by setting its attributes appropriately.

Comment: ok, thanks. If make that into an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Well, I don't consider it an answer per se, just a bunch of advice. If you accept this your question won't get attention from others. Let's give it  some time for possibly a more comprehensive answer. If not I'll post one later.